# Shift values from two separate cells into one using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to combine certain values from separate columns into one 'cell':

**Data**

```
hello   hi      ok      bye
q122    q222    q422    q222
hi      hi      hi      hi
```

**Logic**

```
The first two rows are joined
```

[image]

**Desired**

```
hello_q122  hi_q222   ok_q422   bye_q222
            
hi          hi        hi        hi
```

**Doing**

```
df.columns = (df.iloc[0] + '_' + df.iloc[1])
df = out.iloc[0:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, the first row keeps getting removed.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set second row (`[1]`) by empty strings and filter out first row by `[1:]`:

```
#solution if default header
print (df)
       0     1     2     3
0  hello    hi    ok   bye
1   q122  q222  q422  q222
2     hi    hi    hi    hi

df.columns = df.iloc[0] + '_' + df.iloc[1]
df.iloc[1] = ''
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
  hello_q122 hi_q222 ok_q422 bye_q222
0                                    
1         hi      hi      hi       hi

df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

---

```
#solution if first row is header
print (df)
  hello    hi    ok   bye
0  q122  q222  q422  q222
1    hi    hi    hi    hi

df.columns = (df.columns + '_' + df.iloc[0])
df.iloc[0] = ''
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  hello_q122 hi_q222 ok_q422 bye_q222
0                                    
1         hi      hi      hi       hi
```

Comment: Hi - for some reason the top row keeps getting eliminated. Still troubleshooting

Comment: @Lynn - in file? in final df? Both solutions?